# bash tab completion issues with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, bash, tab-completion

I am having an issue with tab-completion that I am unable to solve. Specifically, whenever I try to tab-complete a directory, the completed directory name appears with a space following it instead of a forward slash to complete the rest. for example

```
~$ python ~/sof
```

tab-completes to

```
~$ python ~/software<space>
```

Instead of

```
~$ python ~/software/
```

Interestingly this does not happen with `cd` but with everything else it does.

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Oh, and is `~/software` a soft link?

Comment: It is a directory. That is just an example, it happens with all directories.

Answer (score 9):

Apparently it is a known bug. Deleting `/etc/bash_completion.d/acroread.sh` solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me too. Oddly enough acroread.sh file says it is meant to handle files with spaces etc in name. While messes up exactly those. Now files with spaces etc can be cp/mv'd without giving quotes. Thanks.